# Add work email address to Gmail on an Android device

Tags: email, gmail, exchange

I want to install my work email address on gmail on an Android device. The device is a Samsung 10" with Lollipop 5.1.1. Gmail version is 5.3.9xxxxxx.
Following this:
[Gmail 5.0 With Exchange Support And Material Design Has Landed | Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/31/gmail-5-0-exchange-support-material-design-landed-apk-download/)
it shows 3 options, the last being "Exchange". My device has only the first 2 options. Why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Exchange` option is only available for users with the `Exchange Services` package installed.  Unfortunately, this package doesn't come installed on all Android phones (as far as I know, only the Nexus devices come with it preinstalled) and isn't available on the Play Store.  However, I did find a [link](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/exchange-services/exchange-services-6-5-1533254-android-apk-download/) where the apk file can be downloaded from.  After installation, the `Exchange` option should appear when attempting to add an account (reboot possibly required).

---

Disclaimer: I myself have a Nexus device and already had the package installed.  I have not attempted to use the link included in this answer and cannot vouch for its safety.